# Why cant i get 2+ domains working on apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, domain

I would like to have 2+ sites running on the same apache server. I cant figure out how to do it. This example file was taken from a [tutorial i found](http://blog.ruski.co.za/page/Install-Mono-on-Ubuntu.aspx). Then i searched for another tutorial online and i cam up with the 2nd file.

Apache seems to use the default unless i disable it. When i enable the default it continues to use my other one until i disable that (and when i enable it, it continues to use the default...). I cant get both of them working at once. How do i configure this?

-edit- I changed the 2nd host (first two lines) made a clone and changed the domain to the ip address so i now have 3 and i still have my ip and domain always the same site and not the (mono) test site + my main site.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.local.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.aspx
    MonoDocumentRootDir "/var/www/test"
    MonoServerPath rootsite "/usr/local/bin/mod-mono-server2"
    MonoApplications rootsite "/:/var/www/test"

    <Directory /var/www/test>
        MonoSetServerAlias rootsite
        SetHandler mono
        AddHandler mod_mono .aspx .ascx .asax .ashx .config .cs .asmx
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Second domain

```
NameVirtualHost MyTestDomain.com:80
<VirtualHost MyTestDomain.com:80>
    ServerName  MyTestDomain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerAlias MyTestDomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp_path
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.aspx
    MonoDocumentRootDir "/var/www/myapp_path"
    MonoServerPath rootsite "/usr/local/bin/mod-mono-server2"
    MonoApplications rootsite "/:/var/www/myapp_path"

    <Directory /var/www/myapp_path>
        MonoSetServerAlias rootsite
        SetHandler mono
        AddHandler mod_mono .aspx .ascx .asax .ashx .config .cs .asmx
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually just need one host definition (the `*:80` in `<VirtualHost *:80>`) and thus just one `NameVirtualHost` statement. (Usually meaning always except you have tons of IPs that server is listening on.) So your config should be like that:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    # No ServerAlias required: Non-Matching domains go here anyway.
    ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.org
    ServerAlias www.example.org
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

For more information, see [the Apache2 docs about virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/) (specifically the name-based section)

Why your approach does not work: If you use a hostname instead of the `*`, this does not mean that this virtual host block is used when this hostname is sent as the `Host` header. It just means that this block is only considered when the IP address the request was sent to matches the IP the hostname resolves to. Short: don't use hostnames there.

Comment: ok THIS worked and i dont know why. Its similar to what i originally tried (look at first revision). I am going to try to get a 3rd site but using SSL

Comment: I do get this warning # /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Restarting web server: apache2[Tue Jul 13 15:30:48 2010] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting ..[Tue Jul 13 15:30:51 2010] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have `NameVirtualHost *:80` somewhere in your config? You need this to turn on multiple domains via name based virtual hosting.

Comment: Where is the config? do you mean the same file? no i dont. I tried NameVirtualHost MyTestDomain.com:80 and NameVirtualHost MyTestDomain.com without luck. -edit- i googled and tried it just now after i notice your answer 1 min in.

Comment: note: both these answers ATM provide no help

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Remove

```
NameVirtualHost MyTestDomain.com:80
```

Switch

```
<VirtualHost MyTestDomain.com:80>
```

To this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Then restart apache

Comment: Then i'd have two `<VirtualHost *:80>`. I did that before. It didnt allow me to have two different sites running at once. Just one or the other on the ip and domain.

Comment: You need a name on all your additional domains.  The first domain (default) should have no name.  Your errorlog should indicate if you have any problems.

Comment: I also get this error ---> Restarting web server: apache2[Tue Jul 13 15:00:33 2010] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting .[Tue Jul 13 15:00:35 2010] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
.

Comment: @BillThor: How do i put names? where? isnt that what i have above?

Comment: Every virtual host should have a name. It's just that the first one is used no matter the name if no other ones matching the request are found.

Comment: My error log shows nothing unusual http://www.pastie.org/1042566

Comment: note: both these answers ATM provide no help

Answer (score 0):

Mike and Mark are both correct. The `NameVirtualHost` argument must exactly match the argument to `<Virtualhost>`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.local.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test2
</VirtualHost>
```

A configuration like this should work for you.

Comment: hmm, this worked and i dont know why. Its similar to what i originally tried (look at first revision). I do get a warning whenever i have `NameVirtualHost *:801

Comment: The NameVirtualHost is required for your setup, which is why it didn't work to begin with. Are you duplicating the NameVirtualHost line?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the setup for a working virtual server. After trials and errors I reached this conclusion and it works perfectly with multiple domains and the default vhost unchanged:

Add `NameVirtualHost *:80` in `ports.conf` or `httpd.conf` and include it above the virtual hosts, or write it straight to `apache2.conf` above includes.

This is the basic working vhost setup:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.info.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.info
ServerName domain.info
ServerAlias *.domain.info
<Directory /var/www/domain.info>
Allow from all
Options +Indexes
ServerSignature Off
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And DNS setup :

```
domain.info.           IN   A          11.11.11.11
www.domain.info.       IN   CNAME      domain.info.
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I went with nginx, never looked at apache since. Old post :) but +1 anyways